# php include returns 1 after content

Tags: template-include

I'm using a customized wordpress loop which allows me to style the post a certain way after a certain amount of post. For example, The first three post will be styled the same, the next 4 post will styled differently from the first three and so forth. It also allows me to add `<div>` sections between the post.

Here is the code php code I am using to accomplish this.

```
if (have_posts()) :
    $count = 0; $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $count++;
        if ($count <= 3 && $paged === 1) :
            if ($count === 1) echo '<div class="break"><h2>Break div | first 3 posts</h2></div>'; ?>


            <div class="first-three">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>
        <?php elseif (3 < $count && $count <= 7 && $paged === 1) :
            if ($count === 4) echo '<div class="break"><h2>Break div | next 4 posts</h2></div>'; ?>


            <div class="next-four">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>
        <?php elseif (7 < $count && $count <= 13 && $paged === 1) :
            if ($count === 8) echo '<div class="break"><h2>Break div | next 6 posts</h2></div>'; ?>


            <div class="next-six">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>
        <?php elseif (13 < $count && $count <= 20 && $paged === 1) :
            if ($count === 14) echo '<div class="break"><h2>Break div | next other 6 posts</h2></div>'; ?>


            <div class="next-other-six">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>
        <?php else :
            if ($count === 21) echo '<div class="break"><h2>Break div | last 6 posts</h2></div>'; ?>

            <div class="last-six">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;
    endwhile; ?>
    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Older posts'); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts'); ?></div><?php
endif;
```

I'm not sure if you needed all of that, but I decided to place it there just in case.

Now here is the part I am having complications with.

```
    <?php elseif (3 < $count && $count <= 7 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 4) echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div> <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:566px;  float:left;"> ', include 'thumbnail-break.php', '</div> '; ?>
```

For this part I added the `include` function to place a template path between the post. It returns the path but it also outputs the number 1 after the content.

How do I get rid of the number 1.

Comment: you may have to post the contents of `thumbnail-break.php` for someone to be able to answer this

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225961/how-to-change-post-count-in-wordpress-loop/225975#225975

Comment: @majick it's just some html in `thumbnail-break.php`

Comment: try switching out the commas `,` for semicolons `;` around include

Comment: i did that and it messed up my html @majick

Comment: also you should probably be using `get_template_part('thumbnail','break');` instead of just include here.

Comment: @majick that worked! it got rid of the 1. I didn't know about the `get_template_part`. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: sweet, as pointed by @Nebri the problem was doing it the way you had echoed the result of the include call (1) as well because the commas made it part of the echo string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use instead of `include('thumbnail-break.php');`:

```
 get_template_part('thumbnail','break');
```

Which is the standard WordPress way of including partial template files from within page templates.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to echo it out while it returns `1` on success.

Do this instead:

```
if ($count === 4) echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div> <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:566px;  float:left;"> '; include 'thumbnail-break.php'; echo '</div> '; ?>
```

Comment: That didn't work, it kind of messed up my html

Comment: It should, but how it messed it up?

Comment: it included the include file 4 times and all other `<div>` elements became unwrapped @samuel ELH

Comment: Please share with us your code using pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) you will find this line:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

Try switching the following:

```
include 'thumbnail-break.php', '</div> '; ?>
```

To:

```
include_once 'thumbnail-break.php', '</div> '; ?>
```

The include_once only returns a true statement, which I don't believe will render in your html. Untested, but let me know how it goes. At the very least you now know why the 1 is emitted.

Comment: `include_once` is a bad practice here as I think it will get that file to be included in the first time only. Just a thought.

Comment: adding the `;` before the `'</div>'; ?>` doesn't work @Nebri